# 'aiohttp.ClientSession' cache doesn't work

Tags: python, client, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I hope to use `aiohttp.ClientSession` cache my connection after be more faster, But i found when i use 'asyncio.sleep' mock the interval time more than 10s the connection will be like first time to connect, the time less than 10s it will be like cached.  How should I do this?

```
async def main():
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(ttl_dns_cache=None,limit_per_host=10)
    trace_config = aiohttp.TraceConfig()
    trace_config.on_request_start.append(on_request_start)
    trace_config.on_request_end.append(on_request_end)
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn,trace_configs=[trace_config])

    await asyncio.create_task(add_task(session,4))
    await asyncio.sleep(15)
    await asyncio.create_task(add_task(session))
    await asyncio.create_task(add_task(session))


async def on_request_start(session, trace_config_ctx, params):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    trace_config_ctx.start = start_time

async def on_request_end(session, trace_config_ctx, params):
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    elapsed = end_time - trace_config_ctx.start
    print("Request took {}".format(elapsed))

async def add_task(session,num=4):
    task = []
    for i in range(num):
        task.append(fetch('xxxx.com',session))
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    results = await asyncio.gather(*task)
    print('=====================')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvloop.install()
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
Request took 0.23638559999999997

Request took 0.24373

Request took 0.2442225

Request took 0.2806297999999998

=====================

Request took 0.17726310000000112

Request took 0.18133539999999826

Request took 0.18915810000000022

Request took 0.22994100000000017

===================== 


**USE 'await asyncio.sleep(5)' OR NOT USE IT**

Request took 0.24224590000000013

Request took 0.24209349999999996

Request took 0.24268460000000003

Request took 0.261196

=====================

Request took 0.04700550000000003

Request took 0.049366400000000255

Request took 0.05276870000000056

Request took 0.051986700000000496

=====================
```

Comment: Do you suspect the DNS lookup speed is the issue? If yes, try to use the `on_dns_resolvehost_start` / `on_dns_resolvehost_end` and `on_dns_cache_hit` / `on_dns_cache_miss` hooks.

Comment: Looking at the docs, the `ttl_dns_cache` default value is 10s. With it set to None, it's supposed to be forever, so it seems like this is either not being used for some reason or there is a bug (possible). If you set it to a large number (say 300) does it behave as expected? If so I'd look at reporting it as a bug